# Avoiding shared_ptr redirection

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm storing a shared ptr and a reference to the shared object inside a wrapper. Does anyone see a chance of a memory leak? Just being cautious...

```
class B;
class A
{
public :
  typedef shared_ptr< B > PB;
  A( PB pb ) :
    m_pb( pb ),
    m_b( *pb )
  { }

  void someFunc()
  {
    // do something with m_b
  }

  PB getB()
  { 
    return m_pb; 
  }
  // in particular, no function returns a ref to B

private :
  PB m_pb;
  B &m_b;

};
```

Comment: If you want to avoid indirection, then using a reference instead of a pointer won't make any difference.

Comment: I thought reference redirection was equal to pointer redirection, which is faster than shared_ptr redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem, as far as both members have the same scope. But a general rule does not recomend to use reference or naked pointer to an object stored in the shared_pointer, as far as lifetime of the object is managed by the shared pointer, and you have bad chance to get things out of your control.

P.S. In the comments KennyTM tells about check on NULL pointer first.